# Python 3 relative path conversion issue

Tags: python-3.x, relative-path

I am currently working with converting Pycrypto over to Python 3.X

Whilst I seem to have the cryptography side working the same cannot be said for the tests
provided with the module :(

I have used the tests under Python 2.64 and all works fine.
I then ran '2to3' over the tests to generate new files in 3.X format.
There are several references to the following:

from .common import make_block_tests

Whenever I run the tests I get:

ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

If someone would point me towards a way to fix this it would be much appreciated :)

Cheers
Grail

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the test files directly, then you can't have relative imports. Change them to be absolute imports, and it will solve the problem.